# Convert Xml to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable

I have an XML file I want to insert that in a Datatable.
The format of the xml file is like below:

```
<userid ID="37729">
  <TestId ID="84" TimeRemaining="60" />
  <QuestId ID="1">
    <Answer1>
    </Answer1>
    <Answer2>B</Answer2>
    <Answer3>
    </Answer3>
    <Answer4>
    </Answer4>
  </QuestId>
</userid>
```

Now I want to insert that in a data table like below:

```
Question Id     Answer1      Answer2        Answer3        Answer4
1                 A                                         D

2                             B              C     

3                                            C
```

Can any one help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please format the data that you need to insert in datatable, properly. It is difficult to understand that way.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need a `DataTable`? You could probably define a serializable class and deserialize this into an object just as easy, and it would likely be more useful in that form.

Comment: @Joe Enos Yeah, like @ColinE suggests, you could use Linq-to-XML.

Comment: @Joe:no there is no any specific, just want to store the XML file in tabular format.. like above example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would first create a `DataTable` with the columns that you require, then populate it via Linq-to-XML.

You could use a Select query to create an object that represents each row, then use the standard approach for creating DataRows for each item ...

```
class Quest
{
    public string Answer1;
    public string Answer2;
    public string Answer3;
    public string Answer4;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");

    var rows = doc.Descendants("QuestId").Select(el => new Quest
    {
        Answer1 = el.Element("Answer1").Value,
        Answer2 = el.Element("Answer2").Value,
        Answer3 = el.Element("Answer3").Value,
        Answer4 = el.Element("Answer4").Value,
    });

    // iterate over the rows and add to DataTable ...

}
```

Comment: but i winder why i get `type expected` after `new()`

Comment: @user1590636 because this code does not compile. I edited the required information into the answer. Another slight mistake was that the overload `XDocument.Load(yourxmlstring)` expects the string to be an [Uri of a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx), and not literal XML - changed the argument name to "filename.xml". when you need to load directly from a string, use a memorystream.

Comment: What if you don't know the name of the elements?

Answer (score 15):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(fileNamePath);
```

Comment: Are you sure the XML provided is of a suitable format for ReadXml?

Answer (score 2):

[How To Read XML Data into a DataSet by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311566) contains some details. Basically, you can use the overloaded [DataSet method ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) to get the data into a DataSet. Your XML data will be in the first DataTable there.

There is also a [DataTable.ReadXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx).

Comment: Are you sure the XML provided is of a suitable format for ReadXml?

Comment: @ColinE, no I'm not sure, especially with the edits to the question. It'll be easy to find out by running the code. IF this approach works, it will avoid having to create the columns and the select statement. If the data source can be tailored to the ReadXml approach, that will save a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code(Recommended)

```
 MemoryStream objMS = new MemoryStream();
 DataTable oDT = new DataTable();//Your DataTable which you want to convert
 oDT.WriteXml(objMS);
 objMS.Position = 0;
 XPathDocument result = new XPathDocument(objMS);
```

This is another way but first ex. is recommended

```
StringWriter objSW = new StringWriter();
DataTable oDt = new DataTable();//Your DataTable which you want to convert
oDt.WriteXml(objSW);
string result = objSW.ToString();
```

Comment: And where is the XML you're going to insert to the DataTable? Please read the question first.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this could be a little older article. but must of the above answers don´t help me as I need. Then I wrote a little snippet for that.

This accepts any XML that hast at least 3 levels (Like this sample):

```
<XmlData>
    <XmlRow>
        <XmlField1>Data 1</XmlField1>  
        <XmlField2>Data 2</XmlField2>  
        <XmlField3>Data 3</XmlField3>  
        .......
    </XmlRow>
</XmlData>

public static class XmlParser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts XML string to DataTable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Name">DataTable name</param>
    /// <param name="XMLString">XML string</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable BuildDataTableFromXml(string Name, string XMLString)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(XMLString));
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable(Name);
        try
        {

            XmlNode NodoEstructura = doc.FirstChild.FirstChild;
            //  Table structure (columns definition) 
            foreach (XmlNode columna in NodoEstructura.ChildNodes)
            {
                Dt.Columns.Add(columna.Name, typeof(String));
            }

            XmlNode Filas = doc.FirstChild;
            //  Data Rows 
            foreach (XmlNode Fila in Filas.ChildNodes)
            {
                List<string> Valores = new List<string>();
                foreach (XmlNode Columna in Fila.ChildNodes)
                {
                    Valores.Add(Columna.InnerText);
                }
                Dt.Rows.Add(Valores.ToArray());
            }
        } catch(Exception)
        {

        }

        return Dt;
    }
}
```

This solve my problem