# how to load nested XML into data table in c#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

i want to convert XML data into data table.my XML file contains many nested tags.how can i display those data in a **data table** using **C#**

```
<school>
   <staff>
      <staffname>raj</staffname>
      <staffname>rani</staffname>
   </staff>
   <students>
      <firstclass>
        <name>nani</name>
        <rollno>1</rollno>
      </firstclass>
      <secondclass>
        <name>rani</name>
        <rollno>1</rollno>
      </secondclass>
</students>
</school>
```

this is the sample file .Now i want to display this data in a Data Table using c#.

can any one help me to solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried anything? And possible ideas how you might want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Xml to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228315/convert-xml-to-datatable)

Comment: @amuz i have tried with a single tag and i got the result like
<details>
<name>akhil<//name>
</details>
i used the same format

Comment: @abhi  i have nearly 1000 xml tags so,its difficult to write for all the tags

Comment: @naveenkumar chk my solution below it will help you out, keep the xml in txt file and give filename in filepath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
 DataSet dsTest = new DataSet();
 dsTest.ReadXml(filepath, XmlReadMode.Auto);
 DataTable dt = dsTest.Tables[0];
```