# c# load xml into combobox

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to c# I'm trying to load data from xml to combobox items with text and values
my xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<roomsgg id="1">
  <rooms id="1">
    <roomtype id="1" name="standard">
      <roomtimeprice id="5">
        <rtid>5</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
      <roomtimeprice id="6">
        <rtid>6</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
    </roomtype>
    <roomtype id="2" name="sweet">
      <roomtimeprice id="7">
        <rtid>7</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
      <roomtimeprice id="8">
        <rtid>8</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
      <roomtimeprice id="9">
        <rtid>9</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
    </roomtype>
    <roomtype id="3" name="gfgfgfgfgfgf">
      <roomtimeprice id="10">
        <rtid>10</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
      <roomtimeprice id="11">
        <rtid>11</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
      <roomtimeprice id="12">
        <rtid>12</rtid>
      </roomtimeprice>
    </roomtype>
  </rooms>
</roomsgg>
```

I want to fill combobox with roomtype text and set the id as value for the item

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
public frmChangeRoom(string hotel_id2)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    hotel_id3 = hotel_id2;
    fillCombo();
}

//view data select type rooms 
void fillCombo()
{
    string mvalue = "1";

    XDocument readrooms = XDocument.Load("http://www.website.com/api/api.php?action=getrooms&hotel_id=" + hotel_id3);
    var mnodes = (from z in readrooms.Descendants("rooms").Where(e => e.Parent.Attribute("id").Value == mvalue)
                  select new
                  {
                      roomtypemainid = (string)z.Element("roomtype").Attribute("id").Value,
                      roomtypemainname = (string)z.Element("roomtype").Attribute("name").Value

                  }).ToList();
    foreach (var z in mnodes)
    {
        ComboboxItem itemz = new ComboboxItem();
        itemz.Text = z.roomtypemainname;
        itemz.Value = z.roomtypemainid;
        sel_typeRoom.Items.Add(itemz);
    }
```

the problem is that only the first wanted element appears which is standard
any idea?

solved :

```
 XDocument readrooms = XDocument.Load("http://www.website.com/api/api.php?action=getrooms&hotel_id=" + hotel_id3);
            readrooms.Descendants("roomtype").Select(p => new
            {
                roomtypename = p.Attribute("name").Value,
                roomtypeid = p.Attribute("id").Value
            }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                ComboboxItem itemz = new ComboboxItem();
                itemz.Text = p.roomtypename;
                itemz.Value = p.roomtypeid;
                sel_typeRoom.Items.Add(itemz);

            });
```

Comment: Convert them into `DataTable` and assign it into `ComboBox`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Xml to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228315/convert-xml-to-datatable)

Comment: the code reads the first result why not all the result?

Comment: Because your `XML` schema is looks like to separate them into 4 tables..

Comment: thanks ... problem solved

Comment: You could also Serialize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting an element that you have only one of it: `"rooms"`. The descendants method doesn't return a list of descendants of the element you gave but the list of descendant elements of that type.

Change your link like this: (*See that the `select` already creates your custom type*)

```
XDocument readrooms = XDocument.Load("http://www.wiseuo.com/api/api.php?action=getrooms&hotel_id=" + hotel_id3);
var mnodes = (from x in readrooms.Descendants("roomsgg")
              where x.Attribute("Id").Value == mvalue
              from z in x.Descendants("roomtype")
              select new ComboboxItem 
              {
                  Value = (string)z.Attribute("id").Value,
                  Text = (string)z.Attribute("name").Value
              }).ToList();
```

With adding your selection on the `parent` element for checking the `id` and then getting all the items it has under it it is like using the `SelectMany` method in the method syntax