# convert xml file into flat file in a tabular format

Tags: c#, xml

I have many XMLs that I want to flatten out and save as a file (as below)using C#. One option that I tried is to use excel to import the file and then call the vba script from c#. Is there any option to do this in C#.

Sample input xml:

```
<request>
    <log-date>11/28/2016 04:48:40</log-date>
    <service-name>getPdf</service-name>
    <request-id>1234</request-id>
    <request-xml>
    <MyRequest xmlns="http://abcd.com">
        <GroupID>123</GroupID>
        <ClientName>ACBD</ClientName>
        <BrokerInfo>
            <BrokerLoginName>9876</BrokerLoginName>
            <FullName>John</FullName>
        </BrokerInfo>
        <BrokerInfo>
            <BrokerLoginName>0987</BrokerLoginName>
            <FullName>Mike</FullName>
        </BrokerInfo>   
    </MyRequestRequest>
    </request-xml>
</request>
```

Expected output file:

```
log-date|service-name|request-id|groupID|ClientName|BrokerLoginName|FullName
11/28/2016 04:48:40|getPdf|1234|123|ACBD|9876|John
11/28/2016 04:48:40|getPdf|1234|123|ACBD|0987|Mike
```

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228315/convert-xml-to-datatable). it might help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

        public static void ReadInnerText()
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myTextFile.txt");
        file.WriteLine("log-date|service-name|request-id|groupID|ClientName|BrokerLoginName|FullName");
        string Line = string.Empty;
        string BrokerLoginName = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList SecondTag;
        XmlNodeList ThirdTag;
        XmlNodeList FourthTag;
        XmlNodeList FifthTag;
        doc.Load("inputFile.xml");
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("request");
        foreach (XmlNode firstNode in elemList)
        {

            SecondTag = firstNode.ChildNodes;
            foreach (XmlNode SecondNode in SecondTag)
            {

                if (SecondNode.Name.Equals("log-date"))
                {
                    Line = SecondNode.InnerText + "|";
                }
                if (SecondNode.Name.Equals("service-name"))
                {
                    Line = Line + SecondNode.InnerText + "|";
                }
                if (SecondNode.Name.Equals("request-id"))
                {
                    Line = Line + SecondNode.InnerText + "|";
                }
                ThirdTag = SecondNode.ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode ThirdNode in ThirdTag)
                {
                    FourthTag = ThirdNode.ChildNodes;
                    foreach (XmlNode FourthNode in FourthTag)
                    {
                        if (FourthNode.Name.Equals("GroupID"))
                        {
                            Line = Line + FourthNode.InnerText + "|";
                        }
                        if (FourthNode.Name.Equals("GroupName"))
                        {
                            Line = Line + FourthNode.InnerText + "|";
                        }
                        if (FourthNode.Name.Equals("ClientName"))
                        {
                            Line = Line + FourthNode.InnerText + "|";
                        }
                        FifthTag = FourthNode.ChildNodes;
                        foreach (XmlNode FifthNode in FifthTag)
                        {
                            if (FifthNode.Name.Equals("BrokerLoginName"))
                            {
                                BrokerLoginName = FifthNode.InnerText + "|";
                            }
                            if (FifthNode.Name.Equals("FullName"))
                            {    
                                file.WriteLine(Line+BrokerLoginName+FifthNode.InnerText);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: THanks! But, I am trying to write  a generic code to parse through different xml schemas without hard coding the tags

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.depth(v=vs.110).aspx