# How to convert xml to ms word doc?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have some XML which are exported from Lotus Notes, these XML have some attachments also like images, ppts, xlsx, doc, docx etc, I want to convert each of these XML files to word document.
I am able to convert this XML to doc files but the attachments are not getting embedded into the converted document.
How can I get these attachments embedded within the converted doc?

the code that I am using is:-

```
try
{
    XPathDocument myXPathDocument = new XPathDocument("c:/Documentation/0C022E9CC8D766B386257F3900665F4D/0C022E9CC8D766B386257F3900665F4D.xml");
    XslTransform myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:/Documentation/0C022E9CC8D766B386257F3900665F4D/0C022E9CC8D766B386257F3900665F4D.doc", null);
    myXslTransform.Load("configX.xslt");
    myXslTransform.Transform(myXPathDocument, null, writer);
    writer.Close();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Question is if Your XML is readable by Word - what You expect to do? Is the info in XML used for formatting Word document or should it appear inside word document as a text?

Comment: `doc` is a binary format. You can't read it as XML. It's also obsolete. `docx` is actually a zip-compressed collection of XML files. You can generate it using the Open XML SDK or a third-party library

Comment: You'll find [a lot of NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=DOCX) that can generate `docx` files

Comment: You may find a solution in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083202/convert-xml-file-into-flat-file-in-a-tabular-format/42091825#42091825